# PHP equivalent of angularJS routing

Tags: php, angularjs

In angularJS you generally have an index page that includes the header and footer directly, and a div such as `<div ng-view></div>` or `<section ui-view></section>` where partial html pages are injected based on a routing file in app.js. For example:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "home/index.html"
    })
    .state('about', {
        url: "/about",
        templateUrl: "about/index.html"
    })
    .state('contact', {
        url: "/contact",
        templateUrl: "contact/index.html"
    })

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})
```

Then whenever someone clicks a hyperlink to a different part of the site, the router decides which partial gets injected into the index page. The problem with this is that the urls include hashtags (example.com/#/home) and you can only get rid of this by configuring the website's server to run html5mode, which I can't do for this particular site.

So I'm wondering what is the PHP equivalent to achieve this type of routing functionality. I figured you can use include() for the header and footer, but am lost on how to handle the actual html partials using php.

Comment: I don't know anything about AngularJS, so maybe I'm misunderstanding your description... but why can't you just `include` the main portion of the page the same way as the header and footer? *What's* the deal with the pound signs?

Comment: Because the main content on each page will differ, whereas the header and footer are always the same. How do I tell PHP to include a different main content page based on the url I am on?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache, you could use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

This PHP variable holds the URI given to access the current page (i.e., URL minus "http://domain.com"). If you had a large number of possible URIs that needed to be handled by a single PHP script, you could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    case "/page1.php": // what to do if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] contains "/page1.php"
        include 'page1.php';
        break; // end of this case
    case "/page2.php":
        include 'page2.php';
        break;
    ...
    default:  // what to do if no match is found
        include '404.php';
}
```